# getting empty index after applying filter to paandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

am trying to apply filter to pandas dataframe, but getting empty index
my df looks like this

[image]

My code is...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(boh), columns = ['MATERIAL', 'Plant', 'BOM Usage', 'Alt. BOM', 'Valid-From Date'])  
print df  
Alternate_bom = df['Alt. BOM'] == 1  
print df[Alternate_bom]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think need compare by string `'1'`:

```
df1 = df[df['Alt. BOM'] == '1']
```

Another possible solution is convert column to `int`:

```
df1 = df[df['Alt. BOM'].astype(int) == 1]
```

Or:

```
df['Alt. BOM'] = df['Alt. BOM'].astype(int)
df1 = df[df['Alt. BOM'] == 1]
```